# UML - Modelling of <<delegate>> connector to an interface or its implementation?

Tags: uml, autowired

I would like to depict **delegation** of one class's method execution to another class. But I am using an wired interface in the class and the implementation is found by dependency injection.

Should I model it by the diagram on the left - like it is stated in the class:

```
public abstract class ComplexClass {
    @Autowired
    private WiredInterface wiredInterface;
    //other stuff

    public Object doSomething {
        return Object wiredInterface.doSomething();
    }
}
```

**OR**

by the injected implementation - diagram on the right?

[image: UML <<delegate>> connector modelling]

I found an example of delegation [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_compositediagram.html) (in the Sparx System UML tutorial) and it is pointing to an interface. That make sense to me, but in some other articles I have got, it is the other way. Please tell me, what is the more suiting approach here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superstructes 2.5 says the following:

> A delegation Connector is a Connector that links a Port to a role within the owning EncapsulatedClassifier. It represents the forwarding of requests (Operation invocations and Signals). A request that arrives at a Port that has a delegation Connector to one or more Properties or Ports on Properties will be passed on to those targets for handling.
>
> Delegation Connectors can be used to model the hierarchical decomposition of behavior, where services provided by an EncapsulatedClassifier may ultimately be realized by one that is nested multiple levels deep within it.
>
> As a ConnectableElement, the effective provided Interfaces (see 11.2.3) of a Port are its provided interfaces, and the effective required Interfaces are its required Interfaces. However, for a delegating Port, i.e., a Port that is at an end of a delegation Connector and is not on a role and that is not a behavior Port, the effective provided Interfaces are its required interfaces and its effective required Interfaces are its provided interfaces. Consequently a delegating Port behaves, for connection, as though it had an internal “face” that is the conjugate of its external “face.”

So I would read this as "delegation goes to an interface".

N.B.: I would not mind a model that uses delegation to implementation if the editor explains its meaning appropriately.